# Difference between Regular JavaScript functions and React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

But what is the difference between both of them ?

From this post it seems like there is no difference and it is just different way of writing.

Please provide an example to make the difference more clear.

Comment: React functions supports JSX compared to regular JS functions

Comment: A function component is a function that returns react elements (or null), and which you intend to use via JSX tags (or React.createElement). All function components are functions, but not all functions are components.

Answer (score 1):

All React Function Components are regular Javascript functions.

Not all regular Javascript functions are React Function Components.

Function components are just a signature for a specific function.

You can look at the Typescript definition to see exactly what that signature is:

```js
    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
        displayName?: string | undefined;
    }
```

Reference: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L542

And `PropsWithChildren` is defined as:

```js
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode | undefined };
```

Reference: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L822

The JSX parser will translate JSX and pass certain parameters to these functions.

JSX:

```
<CompOne someProperty="someValue"><CompTwo/></CompOne>
```

Equivalent to:

```
CompOne({someProperty: "someValue", children: CompTwo({})})
```

The signature is just letting you know how the JSX will be parsed, so you know how to access those parameters within your function.

The signature includes some additional info as well: the function should return a `ReactElement` or `null`, and it can have those four properties.

---

For example, I'm trying to log the `someProperty` value from `CompOne`:

```
<CompOne someProperty="someValue" someOtherProp="someOtherValue" />
```

```
CompOne(someProperty) {
  console.log(someProperty); // logs {someProperty: "someValue", someOtherProp: "someOtherValue"}
  return null;
}
```

This is incorrect, because I was not using the function as the Function Component signature describes. The JSX parser reads the properties into an object, and passes it as the first parameter to the function. Although the code will still execute, it is not what I intended to happen.

```
CompOne(props) {
  console.log(props.someProperty); // logs "someValue"
  return null;
}
```

This works as intended because I know the structure of a Function Component.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my best to keep it as simple as I can for your understanding:-

Javascript functions:-

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

React functional component:-

```
import React from 'react';

const DisplayMessage = (props) => {
  return <h1>{props.message}</h1>;
};

export default DisplayMessage;
```

1. **USE:-** JS functions are particular to do a thing. as you see in the example it will do the addition of two numbers only.while React functional components are used to define components in React that can be rendered to the UI. The display component will render the functional component.
2. **DEFINITION:-** JS functions are defined using the **function** keyword, while React functional components are defined using the **const** keyword and an arrow function.
3. **PROPS:-** We can pass and receive props to react functional components but not too regular JS functions.
4. **STATE:-** JS function doesn't have any state while React functional component when declared in classes will have the state.
5. **RENDERING:-** JS function doesn't render any change in the value.while React functional component re-render on every state or props change.

Comment: thank you so much it helps to me for the understading